# how to make key of map to variable name

Tags: java, variables, dictionary

In java,i have a Map that contains certain values. I want to create a String variable that having the name of the key of the map. How it is possible in java?

```
Map<String,String> values=new HashMap<String, String>();
values.put("dataSource", "bloomberg");
values.put("dataProvider", "bloomberg");
values.put("observationTime", "close");
```

this is the map. And i want to make the variables with values :

```
String dataSource="bloomberg";
String dataProvider="bloomberg";
String observationTime="close";
```

How it is possible in java?

Comment: May I know why do you want to do that?

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible.

Comment: just reference the hashmap, its the perfect datastructure for your requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java doesn't support dynamic variable names. All the variables have to be present at compile time (this means that only the containers would be made at compile time) and at runtime, values are simply assigned and changed according to the logic of the program.

A few languages support creating variables with dynamic names, but it is not possible in Java

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
String dataSourceKey = "dataSource";
String dataSourceValue = "bloomberg";
values.put(dataSourceKey, dataSourceValue);
```

Now, when reading the values from the map

```
String dataSource = values.get(dataSourceKey);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: you missed the point, I think the OP wants the variable names themselves to be determined by whats in the hashmap